# Silverlight app inside of a asp.net page - The remote server returned and error: NotFound

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I've embedded my Silverlight app inside of an asp.net page (of a different project) with the following code:

```
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>  
    </object>
```

And it loads up the GUI just fine. However, when the first call to a database is made I receive the error "CommunicationException was unhandled by user code. The remote server returned and error: NotFound."

The Silverlight app works just fine when I run it alone, but when embedded in this page on this other project it doesn't work correctly. I've included both the ProjectView.Web and the Silverlight App itself in the second projects solution, and I changed the output path of the app to the folder where the .aspx file of the page is located.

I've been looking around for awhile and haven't really found anything that helps, it seems that the error is generic and could be anything. I'm thinking it's not able to find the services references because the paths have changed but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: It sounds like a connection issue to the DB. You have to change the connection string when moving to production.

Answer (score 0):

I like `Entity Framework` for my back end. In the designer it automatically assigns the connection string to the Db on the host computer(development) then when I deploy I use the overload for the container when initialized which is the [Connection String](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=connection%20string&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.connectionstrings.com%2F&ei=U_HYUZG2MqukyAG75YHACA&usg=AFQjCNFp35VmkJSg5VOClxRITQ5sJhjCbQ&bvm=bv.48705608,d.aWc) to the server Db.

```
Public Shared Function ModelConnStr() As String
 Dim sqlcon As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
 sqlcon.DataSource = "tcp:{domain}.com"
 sqlcon.InitialCatalog = "db"
 sqlcon.UserID = "id"
 sqlcon.Password = "pswd"
 Dim mdlcon As New System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder
 mdlcon.Metadata = "res://*/BMModel.csdl|res://*/BMModel.ssdl|res://*/BMModel.msl"
 mdlcon.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient"
 mdlcon.ProviderConnectionString = sqlcon.ConnectionString
 Return mdlcon.ConnectionString
End Function
```

So the same concept applies, use localhost for testing, then before you upload/publish you change the connection string.